# finding an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that there exists an automorphism $\phi$ of $Q_8$ such that $\phi(\sigma)=\nu$ and $\phi(\nu)=\sigma\nu$.

Where $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\pi \frac{i}{2}}&0\\0&e^{-\pi \frac{i}{2}}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\nu=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not
$$\sigma=\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}?$$

Anyway $Q_8$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\nu$ subject to relations
$\sigma^2=\nu^2$, $\sigma^4=I$, $\sigma\nu\sigma^{-1}=\nu^3$.
One can verify that $\sigma'=\nu$ and $\nu'=\sigma\nu$ satisfy the
same relations. This means that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism
from $Q_8$ to $Q_8$, but $\nu=\sigma'$ and $\sigma=\nu'\sigma'^{-1}$
lie in the image, so $\phi$ is onto. Therefore $\phi$ is an automorphism.

Comment: and why $\phi$ is injective? and what is $\rho$?

Comment: @naima $\phi$ is a surjection from a finite set to itself.

Answer (score 0):

$Q_8 = \{e,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\nu,\nu\sigma,\nu\sigma^2,\nu\sigma^3\}$, with $\sigma\nu=\nu\sigma^3$ and $\nu^2=\sigma^2$.

This is the quaternion group with $\nu=i$, $\sigma=j$, and $\nu\sigma=k$.

The automorphism proposed maps $j$ to $i$ and $i$ to $-k$, so it is an automorphism.